# Android space not usable

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, storage

I have a *Moto G 2013* (xt1032) and whenever I check the storage first it shows the free space before calculating everything (393 MB) and later on (after calculation) I see in the bar that the free space is bigger but it still registers 393MB. Why is this?

[image: screenshot] [image: screenshot]